# Receive custom exceptions from Restlet Framework in GWT client

Tags: java, gwt, exception, restlet

I want to use Exception handling with the Restlet Framework and GWT clients.
The Restlet Framework supports the concept of annotated exceptions as described in this post;

http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/21/exception-handling-with-restlet-framework/

In my project i created a LocationNameException

```
@Status(value = 409)
public class LocationNameException extends Exception
{
    ...

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public LocationNameException(String pMessage, Throwable pCause)
    {
        super(pMessage, pCause);
    }
}
```

And use this in my ServerResource;

```
   @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackOn = LocationNameException.class)
    public LocationDto postLocation(LocationDto pLocationDto) throws LocationNameException
    {
        ...

        Location lLocation = new Location(pLocationDto);

        try
        {
            LocationDao lLocationDao = getLocationDao();
            lLocationDao.persist(lLocation);
        }
        catch (PersistenceException pPersistenceException)
        {
            throw new LocationNameException("Location requires unique Name", pPersistenceException);
        }

        ...

        return lLocationDto;
    }
```

With the interface

```
public interface LocationListServerResourceInt
{
    ...

    @Post
    LocationDto postLocation(LocationDto pLocationDto) throws LocationNameException;

    ...
}
```

This works, in the case of an exception the call returns code 409;

[image]

And at the GWT client side onFailure() is called;

```
private class PostLocationCallback implements AsyncCallback<LocationDto>
{
    ...

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable pCaught)
    {
        mCallback.onFailure(pCaught, mLocationDto);
    }
}
```

But parameter pCaught only contains a ResourceException with the status code 409.
My LocationNameException isn't included in the underlying cause stack.
I need this LocationNameException for appropriate error message handling.

The reason is the generated ServerResourceProxy  LocationListServerResourceProxyImpl by the Restlet GWT ClientProxyGenerator;

```
public void postLocation(LocationDto param1, final LocationDto> callback)
{       
    ...

    public void handle(Request request, Response response)
    {
       if (getClientResource().getStatus().isError())
       {       
          callback.onFailure(new ResourceException(getClientResource().getStatus()));
       }
       else
       {

    ...

}
```

I think i have to rewrite the Post method in the ClientProxyGenerator;

[image]

The LocationNameException is present in the Response data so [the Basic approach using the getResponseEntity() method of the ClientResource class should be possible](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/21/exception-handling-with-restlet-framework/).

Is this the way to go? Or can i catch the LocationNameException exception somewhere else as suggested by [Catching annotated exceptions](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/21/exception-handling-with-restlet-framework/)?

It is really hard to try a different approach because of the generated code. Is there an easy way to circumvent the code generator with custom classes?

Comment: It remains awkwardly quiet around this issue ... Is Restlet/GWT still alive? Anyone ever used server exceptions in GWT clients with Restlet?

Comment: Hi Roland, the support for annotated exception in Restlet/GWT hasn't been developed, but it should be technically feasible. Do you think you could contribute it? Happy to support you during this process.

Comment: Hello Jerome, yes i think i can contribute it. The challenge isn't the annotated exception (I can just use the described Basic Approach) but the  ClientProxyGenerator (thus GWT compiler stuff...). I tried to use the generated source code in my project but there are problems with the ServerResourceProxy_TypeSerializer... Do you have a working/compiling ServerResourceProxyImpl/ServerResourceProxy_TypeSerializer example i can play with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Jerome Louvel and Thierry Boileau i created a new ClientProxyGenerator() that supports custom exceptions towards a GWT client;

[image]

Just specify the exception from the interface in the ServerResourceProxy (ClientProxy)

[image]

and voilà

[image]

[image]

It is possible to use this custom ClientProxyGenerator() in your project right away.

[Download custom ClientProxyGenerator](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d5n9AgJP7BXmtIVM17saSEUv-_QQruyS/view?usp=sharing)

And place it in a package on the server (for example package com.ludus.server.util)

[image]

In GWT module XML change the ClientProxyGenerator to the new version on the server;

[image]

And you're ready to go with your custom exceptions, but it would be nice if this extension would be integrated in the Restlet framework.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the LocationNameException is present in the Response data.
Therefore we can get it, just like a normal entity;

```
...

       public void handle(Request request, Response response)
        {
            if (getClientResource().getStatus().isError())
            {
                LocationNameException lLocationNameException = null;
                boolean serializationError = false;

                try
                {
                    if (response.isEntityAvailable())
                    {
                        if (MediaType.APPLICATION_JAVA_OBJECT_GWT.equals(response.getEntity().getMediaType()))
                        {
                            lLocationNameException = new ObjectRepresentation<LocationNameException>(
                                    response.getEntity().getText(),
                                    (SerializationStreamFactory) MyLocationListServerResourceProxyImpl.this, false)
                                    .getObject();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new IOException("Can't parse the enclosed LocationNameException.");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Throwable e)
                {
                    serializationError = true;
                    callback.onFailure(new ResourceException(e));
                }

                if (!serializationError)
                {
                    callback.onFailure(lLocationNameException);
                }
            }
            else
            {

...
```

The ClientProxyGenerator needs to know the exception type (in this case LocationNameException). Therefore we specify the exception in the ClientProxy interface;

```
    @Post
    void postLocation(LocationDto pLocationDto, AsyncCallback<LocationDto> pResult) throws LocationNameException;
```

And use getExceptionTypes() or getGenericExceptionTypes() in the ClientProxyGenerator;

```
    Class<?>[] exceptionTypes = method.getExceptionTypes();
    java.lang.reflect.Type[] genericExceptionTypes = method.getGenericExceptionTypes();
```

Of course not all REST methods use a custom exception. When getExceptionTypes() returns an empty list we just return the good old status code;

```
callback.onFailure(new ResourceException(getClientResource().getStatus()));
```